# Using clocking blocks and modports inside Interfaces

Tags: system-verilog

Can someone give me a hint as to why this interface with modports and clocking blocks might not work?

```
interface axis (input logic aclk );
 logic [15:0] tdata_s;
 logic        tvalid_s;
 logic        tready_s;

 logic [15:0] tdata_m;
 logic        tvalid_m;
 logic        tready_m;


 // clocking block for AXI Stream master
 clocking cb_axis_mst @(posedge aclk);
  default input #1step output #3ns;
  output  tdata_m;
  output  tvalid_m;
  input   tready_m;
 endclocking



 // clocking block for AXI Stream slave
  clocking cb_axis_slv @(posedge aclk);
   default input #1step output #1ns;
   input   tdata_s;
   input   tvalid_s;
   output  tready_s;
  endclocking


  // AXI stream master modport for testbench only
  modport tb_axis_mst_mp(clocking cb_axis_mst);

  // AXI stream slave modport for testbench only
  modport tb_axis_slv_mp(clocking cb_axis_slv);

endinterface
```

QuestaSIM 10.5c gives me a series of errors like this:

** Error: (vsim-3773) ../../../../rtl/test_driver.sv(37): Interface item  'tvalid_m' is not in modport 'tb_axis_mst_mp'.

The problem goes away if I add the ports to the modport, but my understanding was that it was sufficient to just use the clocking block.

Full code is here:  https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5FzC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct. Adding a clocking block to a modport only gives you access to the signals created by the clocking block, not the signals it references.

When using clocking block signals you need to reference the clocking block scope, i.e. `AXIS_MST.cb_axis_mst.tvalid_m`. And instead of `@posedge AXIS_MST.aclk`, just use `@AXIS_MST.cb_axis_mst`.

One other comment about your testbench: remove the nested `program/endprogram` statements; they serve no purpose. [Do not use program blocks](http://go.mentor.com/programblocks).